# Invoking "cmake" failed

Tags: ros, catkin, moveit

I am trying to build a ROS package '**moveit_kinematics**' but getting the following error:

[image]

I ran `find_package(ur3_moveit_plugin REQUIRED)` but getting syntax error.

**CmakeLists.txt**:

```
find_package(trac_ik_kinematics_plugin QUIET)
find_package(ur_kinematics QUIET)

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS filesystem program_options REQUIRED)

set(MOVEIT_LIB_NAME moveit_cached_ik_kinematics_base)
add_library(${MOVEIT_LIB_NAME} src/ik_cache.cpp)
set_target_properties(${MOVEIT_LIB_NAME} PROPERTIES VERSION "${${PROJECT_NAME}_VERSION}")
target_link_libraries(${MOVEIT_LIB_NAME}
    ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY}
    ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
install(TARGETS ${MOVEIT_LIB_NAME} LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION})

if(trac_ik_kinematics_plugin_FOUND)
    include_directories(${trac_ik_kinematics_plugin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
endif(trac_ik_kinematics_plugin_FOUND)

set(MOVEIT_LIB_NAME moveit_cached_ik_kinematics_plugin)
add_library(${MOVEIT_LIB_NAME} src/cached_ik_kinematics_plugin.cpp)
set_target_properties(${MOVEIT_LIB_NAME} PROPERTIES VERSION "${${PROJECT_NAME}_VERSION}")
target_link_libraries(${MOVEIT_LIB_NAME}
    moveit_cached_ik_kinematics_base
    moveit_kdl_kinematics_plugin
    moveit_srv_kinematics_plugin
    ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
if(trac_ik_kinematics_plugin_FOUND)
    target_link_libraries(${MOVEIT_LIB_NAME} ${trac_ik_kinematics_plugin_LIBRARIES})
    set_target_properties(${MOVEIT_LIB_NAME} PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "CACHED_IK_KINEMATICS_TRAC_IK")
endif()
install(TARGETS ${MOVEIT_LIB_NAME} LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION})

# This is just for testing purposes; the arms from Universal Robots have
# analytic solvers, so caching just adds extra overhead.
if(ur_kinematics_FOUND)
    include_directories(${ur_kinematics_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    foreach(UR 3 5 10)
        set(MOVEIT_LIB_NAME moveit_cached_ur${UR}_kinematics_plugin)
        add_library(${MOVEIT_LIB_NAME} src/cached_ur_kinematics_plugin.cpp)
        set_target_properties(${MOVEIT_LIB_NAME} PROPERTIES VERSION "${${PROJECT_NAME}_VERSION}")
        find_library(ur${UR}_pluginlib ur${UR}_moveit_plugin PATHS ${ur_kinematics_LIBRARY_DIRS})
        target_link_libraries(${MOVEIT_LIB_NAME}
            moveit_cached_ik_kinematics_base
            ${ur${UR}_pluginlib}
            ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
        install(TARGETS ${MOVEIT_LIB_NAME} LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION})
    endforeach()
endif()

add_executable(measure_ik_call_cost src/measure_ik_call_cost.cpp)
target_link_libraries(measure_ik_call_cost
    ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
    ${Boost_PROGRAM_OPTIONS_LIBRARY})
install(TARGETS measure_ik_call_cost DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION})

install(DIRECTORY include/ DESTINATION ${CATKIN_GLOBAL_INCLUDE_DESTINATION})
install(DIRECTORY launch DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION})
```

Could someone help me locating the package or pointing out the error? Your help/advice would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Please add your `CMakeLists.txt`

Comment: Hi fruchtzwerg, I added the link to the CmakeLists.txt file.

Comment: https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/1415

Answer (score 1):

I had this `Invoking "cmake" failed` error when I installed `catkin_make -j8` and I had my virtual environment activated at that moment. Then you should try installing it in the Python base environment. If that does not help, follow the ideas at [Installing OpenCV fails because it cannot find “skbuild”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63448467/installing-opencv-fails-because-it-cannot-find-skbuild/65479652#65479652) like:

- re-install catkin,
- or `sudo apt install python-pip`,
- or for Python 3 (thanks for the comment): `sudo apt install python3-pip`.

Comment: thanks for me  (Invoking "cmake" failed) error  fixed after running:    sudo apt install python3-pip

Answer (score 0):

The error says it quiet clearly, it cannot find `ur_moveit_plugin`. Add it in the `find_package()` section of CMakeLists.txt. Make sure the package is installed or cloned in your catkin workspace. You added `find_package(wr3_moveit_plugin REQUIRED)`, but the error is about `ur`, it might be a typo though.

Answer (score 0):

All packages that include *MoveIt* headers have to be compiled using the C++11 standard. Therefore you need to add the line

```
#Enable C++11
add_compile_options(-std=c++11)
```

at the beginning of your *CMakeLists.txt*.

Comment: It's still not working even after adding these lines.