# Couldn't install opencv-python with python version Python 3.6.5 :: Anaconda, Inc

Tags: opencv, anaconda, anaconda3

I have darknet and opencv4.2.0 with Ubuntu 18.04

however I couldn't import CV2 while using python (darknet works well)

when i use `sudo pip3 install opencv-python`
terminal shows[image]

Installing through navigator doesn't work either
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing OpenCV fails because it cannot find "skbuild"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63448467/installing-opencv-fails-because-it-cannot-find-skbuild)

Comment: No, it doesn't work